# Overwrite user role

Tags: plugins, user-roles, user-registration, customization

We're using this registration [plugin](https://wordpress.org/plugins/simplr-registration-form/) to serve as a registration form to new users subscribing to our site.

We have two (2) types of users:

1. Students, and
2. Employers.

Creating two different pages both with specific forms, we assigned the user role for each form to the two types such that:

*on the Student Registration form, the user role is set to "Student" and on the Employer Registration form the user role is set to "Employer"*.

However, once registered, all users who register regardless of which form they used, are assigned the *Student role*.

This is because in Settings > General the New User Default Role is set to *Student*.

We want the forms to overwrite this default, so people who register an employer show up as an employer and not a student.

Is there any way to possibly achieve this?

Answer (score 0):

I don't use this plugin for a while, don't you need to customize the shortcode for each form, one should be role="student" and the other one role="employer".

You can also use the filter

```
add_filter( 'simplr_validate_form', 'my_simplr_validate_form', 10, 3 );
```

A simple example, assuming the page for the registration is 1 for the student and 2 for employers, in functions.php :

```
add_filter( 'simplr_validate_form', 'my_simplr_validate_form', 10, 3 );
function my_simplr_validate_form($errors, $data, $atts){
    if(is_page(1)){
        $role = 'student';          
    }
    elseif(is_page(2)){
        $role = 'employer';          
    }
    else{
        $role = get_post_meta(get_the_ID(), 'simplr_role_lock', true);    
    }
    $atts['role'] = $role;

    return $atts;
}
```

For an eventually error message, that because the post(page) meta key "simplr_role_lock" does not match with the choosen role. So, you can try to unset $errors

```
add_filter( 'simplr_validate_form', 'my_simplr_no_errors', 10, 3 );
function my_simplr_no_errors($errors, $data, $atts){
    if(is_page(1) || is_page(2)){ 
         unset $errors;
    }      

    return $errors;
}
```

Be carefull : Untested !!!

Comment: I tried designating the role in the shortcode as you recommended but I get this error message: "Security: Role specified doesn't match form's designated role"

Comment: Because the role of the content doesn't match with a post meta. If you really have two forms in two different pages, try to change the meta value simplr_role_lock and set it to the role for the page. Other method, you can unset the $errors in another function called by the same filter (unset($errors); return $errors;). I will edit my answer in few minutes.